# Como desabilitar/habilar botão(button) quando input file estiver vazio/selecionado?

Tags: jquery, html

Então, tenho um formulário simples de upload de imagens que eu deixo  button desabilitado. Queria que, quando eu selecionar uma foto ou arquivo no input file, o button habilitar!

```
<div id="botoes" class="clearfix">
    <button id="btnEnvia" name="btnEnvia" class="save abre_load" disabled="true">
        SALVAR
    </button>
</div>

<div id="campos" class="clearfix">
    <label>SELECIONAR FOTOS</label>
    <input id="img" type="file" name="img[]" multiple required/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É possível obter os detalhes do `input` *file* pelo evento [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) e então habilitar o botão, algo como:

```js
$("#img").change(function(){
  $("#btnEnvia").attr("disabled", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="botoes" class="clearfix">
    <button id="btnEnvia" name="btnEnvia" class="save abre_load" disabled="true">SALVAR</button>
</div>

<div id="campos" class="clearfix">
    <label>SELECIONAR FOTOS</label>
    <input id="img" type="file" name="img[]" multiple required/>
</div>
```

Comment: Moçada eu resolvi, coloquei o script abaixo de outros scripts no footer, provavelmente era alguma outra importação de Jquery que tava me avacalhando!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode verificar pelo `files.length` usando jquery:

```
if ($('#img').get(0).files.length === 0) {
    //aqui você desativa o seu botão
    document.getElementById("btnEnvia").disabled = true;
    }
else
    {
      //aqui você habilita o botão
      document.getElementById("btnEnvia").disabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: Sugestão: https://jsfiddle.net/c3n17ufd/

Comment: Show cara, resolvido aqui!

Comment: Que bom que resolveu, não esquece de marcar como resposta.